A closed formula for a sum involving hypergeometric functions
Can we find a closed formula for  this sum:
$$\sum_{p,q\geq 0} (p+q+1)r^{p+q} \frac{{}_1F_1(1+p;2+p+q;r^2)}{{}_1F_1(1+p;2+p+q;1)}$$
where
$$_1F_1(a;c;z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a)_n}{(c)_n n!} z^n$$
and
$$(a)_n = a(a+1)(a+2)\dotsm(a+n-1)=\frac{\Gamma(a+n)}{\Gamma(a)},\quad 0<r<1?$$

That seems extremely unlikely, since the denominator of the summand is so complicated. Did you encounter this sum in any natural context?

@HjalmarRosengren I wanted to post a very similar comment today. Even the diagonal sum $p=q$, which can be rewritten using BesselI, is not traceable with this combination of numerator and denominator. I already thought of a typo in the formula. I would also be interested in the context.
